# How to generate a JWT and get it back to my app Angular, Node, Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication

I am building some authentication for my app. Right now, I am posting to my server where a JWT is created. I send the token back, but I'm not sure how to capture it. I'm using Node/Express on the server and Angular on the front end. Here's the endpoint and Angular function.

```
app.post('/session', function (req, res, next){
        var username = req.body.username
        // validate password
        var token = jwt.encode({username: username}, secretKey)
        res.json(token)
    })

$scope.login = function (username, password) {
          console.log('submitting to server')
          var creds = {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
          }
          var token = $http.post('http://localhost:3002/session', creds)
          console.log(token)
        }
```

An object is printed instead of a token. I can see the token is being generated properly because I was able to print it to the server's console as well as generate one through postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a more precise answer...

You are very very close, right now you have

```
    var token = $http.post('http://localhost:3002/session', creds)
```

Which is not setting token to the actual token, it is setting token to a promise. This is good, this is what you want to be doing.

But then, from that you have to act on that promise, you could do

```
    token.then(function(res){
      // res.data should contain your token
      console.log(res.data) 
    })
```

as mentioned before but here is a tiny bit better way...

```
    var tokenReq = $http.post('http://localhost:3002/session', creds);

    tokenReq.success(function(data) {
      // This will fire when the request is successfull
      // data will contain the response, from there you could
      // find your token
      console.log(data);
    }

    tokentReq.error(function(data) {
      // This will fire if the request is not successfull
      console.log('Something went wrong!', data);
    }
```

Handles all situations very neatly.

One thing that always confused me when talking about promises as .success or .error, I always asked myself, "how in the world does it know it's a success or an error?"

It's decided by the status code of the response, so if you set the status code to 500, 404 or something like that, it will trigger the .error, 200 etc to trigger .success.

**EDIT**: One more thing, it looks like it is possible that you are not sending the correct data back. I could be wrong, but I don't think you can just send the token inside of res.json(token), I don't think it would be valid JSON. I don't feel like running my project to test, but this is what I do...

```
    var token = createToken(user);
    res.json({
      token: token,
      userData: user
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to manually set the status code like res.sendstatus(200) or can it be implicit? I've noticed that I get status codes in postman regardless of whether I explicitly send one from the server.

Comment: Yeah some things will automatically send a certain status, I believe doing res.json automatically sends it as 200

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain your $http with a .then()

```
$scope.login = function (username, password) {
          console.log('submitting to server')
          var creds = {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
          }
          $http.post('http://localhost:3002/session', creds)
          .then(function(res){
             // res.data should contain your token
             console.log(res.data) 
           })
        }
```